# Can't insert a <polygon> inside an <svg> by printing its html with {@html} in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svg, svelte

This is my parent component:

```
<script>
    import ObjOne from './ObjOne.svelte'
</script>

<svg width="182px" height="146px" viewBox="0 0 182 146">
    <ObjOne></ObjOne>
</svg>
```

And this is ObjOne:

```
<script>
  let html = '<polygon id="Path" fill="#999999" points="109.9999 146.25 109.9999 98.75 182.4999 98.75 182.4999 146.25" />'
</script>

{@html html}
```

The polygon doesn't render, unless I put the `<polygon>` directly in the component's body, as you can see in the REPL. Is there any workaround? I need to dynamically insert elements in an `<svg>`. I tried with `version` and `xmlns` properties on the `<svg>` but it didn't help.

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/14b354d830184a8d994cae6d223e4c85?version=3.49.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with how `@html` generates elements in SVG. In this case the compiler does not have enough context to know that the element is supposed to be an SVG element, so it will end up with the wrong namespace (HTML).

As a workaround you could add a dummy group:

```html
<g>{@html html}</g>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is a bit disappointing. Just out of curiosity - shouldn't it be obvious to the compiler that the element is an SVG, since the tag is polygon? :)

Comment: Well, theoretically maybe. This does not hold for all elements (e.g. `a` exists in both) and custom elements might also cause issues, though they should contain a dash as far as I know.